# SendKeys não funciona na maquina que vai executar

Tags: c#, winforms, windows, selenium-webdriver

estou fazendo uma automação que eh necessário dar um SendKeys porém quando executo ele na outra maquina em que vai rodar a automação ela não faz a função.

```
            DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(Diretorio);
            com o parametro)
            FileInfo[] Arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles();
            string file = null;
            foreach (FileInfo arquivo in Arquivos)
            {
                file = arquivo.Name;
                Diretorio = string.Concat(@"C:\Users\Robo_RA\Desktop\Anexo\", ID, @"\",file);
                browser.FindFirstElement(By.XPath("input[class='form-control-file validacao']")).ClickJs();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

               // ja tentei
                SendKeys.Send(Diretorio);
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
              // esse tambem
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(Diretorio);
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
            }
```

Comment: Dê detalhes da máquina onde funciona e na onde não funciona.

Comment: @CypherPotato Onde funciona eh um windows 10, rodando no VS, e onde não funciona eh um windows 7 desktop... ja atualizei o framework.

Comment: Normalmente isso é prevenção de *Shatter Attack* do próprio Windows. As aplicações estão sendo executadas em modo elevado?

Comment: Desabilitei o UAC, funcionaNdo... vlw

Answer (score -1):

Ola meu Nome e Giovane.
pelo que entendi o erro não esta na logica e sim na implementação
já utilizei selenium uma vez geralmente isso funciona de mandar depois o sendkeys isso e uma gabiarra ao meu ver pois sendkeys e enviado pelo form não pelo selenium.

utilize isso:

```
browser.FindFirstElement(By.XPath("input[class='form-control-file validacao']")).SendKeys(Diretorio);
browser.FindFirstElement(By.XPath("input[class='form-control-file validacao']")).Click();
```

eu sei que a Pergunta e de 2019 mas acho que ainda pode ser útil a resposta.